# Comparing two lists and removing each item that contains an entry from the other list

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I'm trying to essentially copy any list items in `fileManifest` but only those that don't contain in any of the items from `exclusionFilters` to a newly initialized list.
 I haven't figured out an elegant way to do this other than a nested `foreach` loop.

Does someone by chance have a better solution for this problem? Maybe `LINQ`?

```
var fileManifest = new List<string>()
{
   @"C:\Test\Directory1\File1.xml",
   @"C:\Test\Directory1\File2.xml",
   @"C:\Test\Directory1\Directory2\File1.xml",
};

var exclusionFilters = new List<string>()
{
  @"Directory2\"
};

var filteredList = new List<string>();
```

Expected Output of `filteredList`:

- `C:\Test\Directory1\File1.xml`
- `C:\Test\Directory1\File2.xml`

Comment: Shall `@"C:\Test\OtherDirectory2\File3.xml"` be included or excluded? Please, note, `OtherDirectory2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
var filteredList = fileManifest.Where(x => exclusionFilters.All(y => !x.Contains(y))).ToList();
```

Description:

- [`Enumerable.Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-3.1) Method: Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.
- [`Enumerable.All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netcore-3.1) Method: Determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.
- [`String.Contains(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Contains_System_String_) Method: Returns a value indicating whether a specified substring occurs within this string.
- [`Enumerable.ToList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netcore-3.1) Method: Creates a List from an IEnumerable.