# test if string value is contained in array of strings

Tags: c#, arrays, string, contains

Hi I have a list of words which i am looking for if this word is found i want the valuye removed from my array

```
private static string[] WordList = { "Example No", "Name", "Client ID"};

var listToTest = new[] { "ME 0.3", "Example No.: 1243", "Name.:"};

var newList= new List<string>();
foreach (var value in listToTest)
{
    if (!WordList.Any(x => x.Contains(value)))
    {
        newList.Add(value);
    }
 }

return newList.ToArray();
```

my test returns all the value where I only want it to return **"ME 0.3"**

Comment: ``WordList``  instead of ``Noise``.you should loop on `WordList` not on `listToTest`, because `"Example No".Contains("Example No.: 1243")` will gives always false.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing two lists and removing each item that contains an entry from the other list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62831519/comparing-two-lists-and-removing-each-item-that-contains-an-entry-from-the-other)

Comment: it was a copy and paste error i have edited question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!WordList.Any(x => x.Contains(value))` will return `true` if no element in `WordList` contains `value` and `false` if there is at least one element in `WordList` that contains `value`.

So your code will return an array of elements of `listToTest`, that no element in `WordList` contains them, but as you said you want an array of elements of `listToTest` that they contain no element of `WordList`. So in `... x.Contains(value)))` replace `x` and `value` with each other:

```cs
private static string[] WordList = { "Example No", "Name", "Client ID"};

var listToTest = new[] { "ME 0.3", "Example No.: 1243", "Name.:"};

var newList= new List<string>();
foreach (var value in listToTest)
{
    if (!WordList.Any(x => value.Contains(x)))
    {
        newList.Add(value);
    }
 }

return newList.ToArray();
```

By the way there is a neater way:

```cs
var result = listToTest.Where(x => !WordList.Any(y => x.Contains(y))).ToArray();

// Usage:
foreach (var s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s);

// Output:
// ME 0.3
```

Description:

- [`Enumerable.Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-3.1) Method: Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.
- [`Enumerable.Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netcore-3.1) Method: Determines whether any element of a sequence exists or satisfies a condition.
- [`Enumerable.ToArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToArray__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) Method: Creates an array from a IEnumerable.
- [`String.Contains(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Contains_System_String_) Method: Returns a value indicating whether a specified substring occurs within this string.

Answer (score -1):

Not the most efficient, but works.

```
  newList = listToTest.Where((x) =>
  {
      return WordList.Where(x2 => x.IndexOf(x2) != -1).Count() == 0;
  }).ToList();
```